# How to transfer 250 or so Safari browser tabs to a new iPad?

Tags: browser, safari, browser-tabs, ios, ipad

I have an iPad Pro which I have for a few years now. Now with the new keyboard for the iPad Pro, I decided it's a good time to upgrade to the newest iPad Pro with the new keyboard. The problem is about my Safari tabs: I have about 250 of them and it kind of functions as my to-do list. How can I transfer all those 250 or so tabs to the new iPad?

Are those browser tabs included in my iCloud backup, so that all browser tabs appear automatically on the new iPad? If not, how can I transfer all my tabs to the new iPad?

Btw, they will have the same iCloud and my current iPad has the latest iPadOS.

Answer (score 0):

If you've enabled Safari syncing via the same iCloud account on both devices, then when you go to create a new tab on iPad you can see all the tabs that are open on the Mac. If worse comes to worst you could tap on them one at a time to open each one up on your iPad.

Comment: Hi @Spiff thanks for your suggestion. I indeed figured out that this or Airdrop is a possibility, but that's not exactly what I'm hoping for ;)